# How to open images in a separate window?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I have a table below where it lists each image(s) for each question.

```
    <table id="tableqanda" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%" class="questionno">Question No.</th>
            <th width="11%" class="image">Image</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
        <div id="tableqanda_onthefly_container">
        <table id="tableqanda_onthefly" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <?php
              foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {
            echo '<tr class="tableqandarow">'.PHP_EOL
echo '<td width="5%" class="questionno">'.htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]).'</td>' . PHP_EOL;
            echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">';
            if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
                echo '&nbsp;';
            } else {
                echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
                echo implode("</li>\n<li>", array_map(function($imgitem){
                return htmlspecialchars($imgitem);
            },  $arrImageFile[$key]));
                echo '</li></ul>';
            }
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
            }
    ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Now at the moment it just lists the image file names in a bullet point list. But what I want to do is that I want to set each file as a hyperlink so that if the user clicks on an image link, it will display that image in a separate page (a separate window will open up) displaying the image itself

My question is how can this be done, what are the following steps I need to do? If somebody can show me how to code it step by step then I can use it for audios and videos as well.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your image being outputted? You don't need the php processing code in your second snippet to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've been thinking about what you want to do and I think you want to show a list of images as thumbnails or something, and then click an image and show it (within your layout) on  a new page (previewimage.php).

You have a lot of options... but they all boil down to passing some information through the URL (example.com/previewimage.php).

First, let's examine 2 typical ways to pass information through an URL

**$_GET Request**

Sometimes you'll see a website pass add information to a URL, like

```
example.com/previewimage.php?var=xxx
```

This allows you to pass some information to your PHP script via the $_GET superglobal.

**Htaccess**

If you want to get kind of fancy, you can use htaccess to make a clean URL

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ previewimage.php?var=$1
```

This will let you have an URL like example.com/xxx and the server will act like you went to example.com/previewimage.php?var=xxx.

Now that you know how to hand information off to the url, we can look into some methods for using the $_GET['var'] to show the image.

The easiest approach is to simply pass the name of the file... for this example let's call it example.png.

If you're using the basic $_GET Request method above, you would have an URL like example.com/previewimage.php?var=example.png.

Then, in previewimage.php, you simply do something like

```
<img src="<?php echo $_GET['var'] ?>"/>
```

This will output

```
<img src="example.png"/>
```

However, this is not a very safe method, as anyone can load anything they want.   A better option might be using an array or a database, and then passing a key of some sort and retrieving the filename.

I think this will set you on the right path (and I hope it answers your question).

Comment: The problem I am getting straigt away is surrounding the image names in hyperlinks, I get errors when trying to do this. I think I am placing it in the wrong place but I want to know how to correctly set up the hyperlinks for each image file name? I will use a GET request and using that GET find images which matches the image name selected. Let me ask you how to set the hyperlinks up correctly, then I will be able to take it from there. Thanks

Comment: Aha!  Okay, in that case please see Jaspal Singh's answer, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this question is how to open a link in a new tab.
Surround whatever you like, image in this case, with this.

```
<a href="/linktoimage.png" target="_blank"><img src="/linktoimage.png" alt="my image"></a>
```

Comment: I removed second snippet of code. My question is how do I surround my code in the `<a>` tag and then display the correct image on the separate page (`previewimage.php`) page depending on the image file name link selected?

Comment: @user1723760 TJohnW's code will open the image in a new page.  It will, in fact, just open that file in a new browser window/tab.  Are you trying to display the image within you website's layout?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of how this could be done. Just made edits to the inner "If else" loop

Replace YOUR_BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGES_HERE_ENDING_WITH_A_DASH with the directory path of the images on server.

```
if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
    echo '&nbsp;';
} else {
    echo '<ul class="qandaul"><li>';
    echo implode("</li>\n<li>", array_map(function($imgitem) {
                        return '<a href="YOUR_BASE_URL_FOR_IMAGES_HERE_ENDING_WITH_A_DASH' . htmlspecialchars($imgitem) . '" target="_blank">' . htmlspecialchars($imgitem) . '</a>';
                    }, $arrImageFile[$key]));
    echo '</li></ul>';
}
```

Comment: Does this help ? If not can you give some feedback?

Comment: I will test this out, sorry I did not see your answer